# Как установить индекс текущей строки в datagridview?

Tags: c#, winforms

Программно выделяю строку в гриде:

```
 int i=10; //(пусть будет 10, это не важно)
 DatagridView_MAIL.Rows[i].Selected = True;
```

Отрабатывает событие SelectionChanged в гриде. CurrentRow.Index равно нулю... помогите , пожалуйста, понять почему не 10. И каким образом мне не только выделить строку с индексом 10, но и в свойство CurrentRow.Index записать 10?

Comment: Попробуйте использовать событие [DataGridView.RowStateChanged](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.rowstatechanged(v=vs.110).aspx). Если при выделении строки она получает фокус, думаю получает, то будет работать. Сам проверить пока не могу

Comment: Если честно, то не понял.

Comment: Подпишитесь на это событие, в аргументах есть линк на строку, которая его активировала. По описанию - активация события происходит, в том числе, при смене фокуса. По логике, при выделении строки, она должна получать фокус. По этому признаку можно определить выделенную строку. Пока это только теория на основе документации, когда смогу проверить сам, отпишусь ответом, но вероятно, что вы сможете проверить это быстрее

Comment: Спасибо, буду пробовать

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`CurrentRow`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.currentrow.aspx) возвращает строку в которой находится активная ячейка ([`CurrentCell`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.currentcell(v=vs.110).aspx)). Выделение строки/строк не изменяет текущую активную ячейку.

Попробуйте установить активную ячейку напрямую:

```
//допустим ячейка в первом столбце 11-й строки
DatagridView_MAIL.CurrentCell = DatagridView_MAIL.Rows[10].Cells[0];
```

Comment: Спасибо, но не помогло. Выделяет строку по данному индексу, но RowIndex не изменилось.

Comment: @АлександрПузанов проверил код, `CurrentRow.Index` непосредственно после установки ячейки возвращает 10. Где проверяете индекс? Можете [пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) построить?

Comment: Это да... Но в методе ...SelectionChanged() значение не 10, после его выполнения оно равно 10.

Comment: @АлександрПузанов При установке `CurrentCell` событие `SelectionChanged` не вызывается. Возможно остался старый код который устанавливает `Selected` строке. Вызывается ли он до или после установки ячейки?

Comment: Я подписался на это событие и компилятор сразу перекидывает на него.

Comment: Нужно выяснить устанавливается ли ячейка до или после события (поставить две точки останова и проверить).

Comment: После данного DatagridView_MAIL.CurrentCell = DatagridView_MAIL.Rows[10].Cells[0]; компилятор позиционирует в событие SelectionChanged. Во время обработки этого события индекс не изменился, после его отработки - изменился. Именно в этом событии мне нужен индекс выделенной строки

Comment: @АлександрПузанов понял, что Вы имеете ввиду. `SelectionChanged` вызывается до изменения активной ячейки. Есть ли возможность использовать событие `CurrentCellChanged` вместо него?

Comment: в принципе -да, возможность есть. И ваш вариант становится рабочим для этого события.

Answer (score 2):

При изменении свойства `DataGridViewRow.Selected`, также меняется свойство `DataGridViewRow.State`. Изменение значения `DataGridViewRow.State` активирует событие [DataGridView.RowStateChanged](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.rowstatechanged(v=vs.110).aspx).

В аргументах события есть свойство `DataGridViewRowStateChangedEventArgs.Row`, через которое, вы получаете прямую ссылку на объект `DataGridViewRow`, представляющий выделенную строку.

В обработчике нужно поставить фильтр, чтобы срабатывание происходило только при выделении, например так:

```
private void DataGridView1_RowStateChanged(Object sender, DataGridViewRowStateChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if(e.StateChanged == DataGridViewElementStates.Selected)
    {
        var selectedRow = e.Row;
        //что-то делаем с выбранной строкой
    }
}
```

Естественно, если вам нужно обрабатывать и другие состояния строк, то логику фильтра придется менять.

Отдельно надо заметить, что при таком способе выделения строки, не меняется выделенная ячейка, и соответственно не меняется связанное свойство [DataGridViewRow.CurrentRow](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.currentrow(v=vs.110).aspx), что и является причиной того, что вы не могли получить нужный индекс.

Если вам нужно чтобы изменилось именно свойство `DataGridViewRow.CurrentRow`, то нужно выделить любую ячейку, интересующей вас строки с помощью свойства [DataGridView.CurrentCell](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.currentcell(v=vs.110).aspx).

При использовании текущего способа выделения строки нужно немного изменить обработчик события.

```
private void DataGridView1_RowStateChanged(Object sender, DataGridViewRowStateChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if(e.StateChanged == DataGridViewElementStates.Selected)
    {
        var selectedRow = e.Row;
        dataGridView1.CurrentCell = e.Row.Cells[0];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`DataGridView` есть свойство `CurrentCell` а у него `RowIndex`.
В обработчике собития `SelectionChanged` найдете индекс выбранной строки таким образом:

```
datagridview.CurrentCell.RowIndex
```

Comment: Доступ только для чтения... Другие варианты есть?

Comment: **записать 10** ??имеете ввиду сразу попасть на 10-ую строку?

Comment: Я выделяю строку с индексом 10 и хочу ,чтобы datagridview.CurrentCell.RowIndex было равно 10. А так выделена 10 строка, а это свойство равно нулю.

Comment: Суть в том, что значение .RowIndex изменяется только при нажатии мышки или при помощи клавиатуры, но никак не программно.